# return-question

Tags: perl, return-value

```
sub routine1 { 
    return wantarray ? () : undef;
}

sub routine2 { 
    return;
}
```

Is there any difference between this two subroutines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

From [perldoc -f return](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html):

> If no EXPR is given, returns an empty
>   list in list context, the undefined
>   value in scalar context, and (of
>   course) nothing at all in a void
>   context.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a difference...

Take a look at this link from [Perl Critic](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/Subroutines/ProhibitExplicitReturnUndef.pm).

> Returning undef upon failure from a
>   subroutine is pretty common. But if
>   the subroutine is called in list
>   context, an explicit return undef;
>   statement will return a one-element
>   list containing (undef). Now if that
>   list is subsequently put in a boolean
>   context to test for failure, then it
>   evaluates to true. But you probably
>   wanted it to be false.

It's subtle, but could be an issue.

Comment: This doesn't apply here. `undef` is not being returned in list context.